# cardano-cli Command failed: transaction sign Error: Failed to decode neither the cli's serialisation format nor the ledger's CDDL serialisation [...]

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction

I have a CBOR and want to sign the transaction using the Cardano-cli.

This is the error I get:

```
Command failed: transaction sign  Error: Failed to decode neither the cli's serialisation format nor the ledger's CDDL serialisation format. TextEnvelope error: jpgCbor.body: TextEnvelope decode error: DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "Shelley TxBody" (DeserialiseFailure 568 "expected list start")
TextEnvelopeCddl error: jpgCbor.body: TextEnvelopeCddl type error:  Expected one of: Witnessed Tx Byron, Witnessed Tx Shelley, Witnessed Tx AllegraEra, Witnessed Tx MaryEra, Witnessed Tx AlonzoEra, Unwitnessed Tx Byron, Unwitnessed Tx Shelley, Unwitnessed Tx AllegraEra, Unwitnessed Tx MaryEra, Unwitnessed Tx AlonzoEra Actual: TxBodyAlonzo
```

And this is the jpgCbor.body file:

```
{
    "type": "TxBodyAlonzo",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "84a800828258203c2a4016b855cfee8d661cd169250c304dbd4c5a41cff5f54cfff9c9a91fcf9a0182582057cc7d6da94e8b89da399aad0358a211eea801aa4065d59bcd8c09324d160027000185825839018557ea6f0e3ea5bc9d85a9d6b0e13707411073fa94c955901afb8f3c658203e43a0d07909fab7b5c8127cb89c9ed0a237fb745b37a3e546f1a000f42408258390170e60f3b5ea7153e0acc7a803e4401d44b8ed1bae1c7baaad1a62a721e78aae7c90cc36d624f7b3bb6d86b52696dc84e490f343eba89005f1a000f424082583901def9fafd9028d9d3d9889fc3a8ac689d675909444e749555c56262ee771930a167f20ba82bc54ff63914994d77e99762934c4350cc85acca1a002dc6c082583901d53ccc709879133c6c9dfbc8960f93dd8f88c5da823458bc7875ba95110d0f13d97bb388732d80479214540a9ad4c1431347f588d0feab14821a0016926da1581c2e18377bb0fc8961934e5274e3c7c2161b7d5fd81c28589fe8e62a3aa147426c75653137380182583901d53ccc709879133c6c9dfbc8960f93dd8f88c5da823458bc7875ba95110d0f13d97bb388732d80479214540a9ad4c1431347f588d0feab141a0035d74b021a000a675a031a0443bc95081a0443ae850b582062422a9db0edff27e2313e503da8a0f9492884bd5f337cb42700b2fdbf13daa00d81825820e00b84e9642460e4789533763c1967007771c6211a898c80911a58923ab239fd010e81581cd53ccc709879133c6c9dfbc8960f93dd8f88c5da823458bc7875ba95a30381590fc1590fbe0100003233223232323322333222323233322232333222323332223322323322323332223232332233223232332232323332223322332233223322323232323232323232323232332232323232323232323322323232332232333322223232323232322232232325335305c33223530310012235303500222222222322235304400c23232325335306f333222533530723300300200110731074506e32353047001220023253353505a00113507649010350543800221002302e5002004107115335304a01313301b49101350033355029302f1200123535505e00122323355030335502d30331200123535506200122353550640012253353506f335503533550250490040062153353507033550363335550323039120012235355069002232233225335350770022130020011507800425335350763335502c0500040072153353080013304d0010031335503d5079300400215335308001330630010031335503d507933335502e0510053304900100300215078150773200135508601225335350680011506a2213535506e002225335308201330530020071003133506d33550710020013006003350720010022133026491023130003322333573466e200080041f41f8cc8cd54c0ec48004d40c00048004cd40c40952000335530321200123535506900122001001004133573892010231310007a133573892010231320007900233233553023120013503500135034001335038223355302c120012353550630012233550660023355302f12001235355066001223355069002333535502b0012330264800000488cc09c0080048cc09800520000013355302c1200123535506300122335506600233353550280012335530301200123535506700122335506a00235502f0010012233355502804a0020012335530301200123535506700122335506a00235502d001001333555023045002001505e33233553023120012253353506c3003002213350610010021001505f2353053001222533530763332001504100600313506f0021506e011320013333555028302f1200122353055002225335307333044002500b10031333355502c303312001235305a00122253353506e333550245042003001213333550265043004335530301200123535506700122335506a002333535502c0012001223535506b002223535506d0032233550703302c00400233553039120012353550700012233550730023335355035001200122330310020012001333555030052003001200133355502704900300100213333550255042003002001003001505b500113301b49101340033355029302f1200123530540012233043500a00250011533535058335530401200123320015051320013530460012235305100122253353506b0012321300100d3200135507f2253353506100113507d491022d310022135355067002225335307b3304c00200710011300600313507a49101370050011350744901013600221335530421200123320015053320013530480012235305300122253353506d0012321300100f32001355081012253353506300113507f491022d310022135355069002225335307d3304e00200710011300600313507c4910137005003133355301d12001225335306f335306a303e302d35304600222001207125335307033041001300401010721350764901013300133505a0020011001505900d3200135507622533535058001135074491022d31002213530470022253353072333200150710020071353063303000122335306f00223507b491022d310020011300600315335350520011306d4988854cd4d41500044008884c1c5263333573466e1d40112002203a23333573466e1d40152000203a23263530663357380b80ce0ca0c80c66666ae68cdc39aab9d5002480008cc0c4c8c8c8c8c8c8c8c8c8c8c8cccd5cd19b8735573aa01490001199999999981f99a828919191999ab9a3370e6aae7540092000233045304b35742a00460986ae84d5d1280111931a983a99ab9c06b076074073135573ca00226ea8004d5d0a80519a8288241aba1500935742a0106ae85401cd5d0a8031aba1500535742a00866a0a2eb8d5d0a80199a82899aa82b3ae200135742a0046ae84d5d1280111931a983899ab9c06707207006f135744a00226ae8940044d5d1280089aba25001135744a00226ae8940044d5d1280089aba25001135573ca00226ea8004d5d0a80119191999ab9a3370e6aae75400520022303a303e357426aae7940088c98d4c1a0cd5ce02f03483383309baa001357426ae8940088c98d4c194cd5ce02d833032031883289931a983219ab9c49010350543500065063135573ca00226ea80044d55ce9baa001223370000400244a66a60ac00220b0266ae7000815c4488c88c008004c8004d5417c894cd4d41040045413c884d4d5411c008894cd4c16ccc02000801c4d41500044c01800c448888c8cd54c03c480048d4d5411800488cd54124008ccd4d5402c0048004880048004ccd554018014008004c8cd40054109410c488cc008cd5411c014010004444888ccd54c0104800540fccd54c030480048d4d5410c00488cd54118008d5402c004ccd54c0104800488d4d54110008894cd4c160ccd54c06048004d4034cd403c894cd4c168008417040041648d4d5411c00488cc028008014018400c4cd410c01000d4100004cd54c030480048d4d5410c00488c8cd5411c00cc004014c8004d54184894cd4d410c0044d5402c00c884d4d54124008894cd4c174cc0300080204cd5404001c0044c01800c008c8004d5416888448894cd4d40fc0044008884cc014008ccd54c01c480040140100044484888c00c01044884888cc0080140104484888c00401044800448cd404888ccd4d401000c88008008004d4d40080048800448848cc00400c00848004c8004d541488844894cd4d40d8004540e0884cd40e4c010008cd54c018480040100044448888cccd54011403c00c0040084488cd54008c8cd403c88ccd4d401800c88008008004d4d401000488004cd401005012800448848cc00400c008480044488c0080048d4c08c00488800cc8004d5412c88c8c94cd4c114cc0a14009200213300c300433530081200150010033004335300d12001500100310031332233706004002a002900209999aa9801890009919a80511199a8040018008011a802800a8039119b800014800800520003200135504a221122253353502f00113500600322133350090053004002333553007120010050040011235350050012200112353500400122002320013550472212253353041333573466e2400920000430421502d153353502b0011502d22133502e002335300612001337020089001000899a801111180198010009000891091980080180109000990009aa821911299a9a81300108009109a980a801111a982180111299a9a8160038a99a9a8160038804110b1109a980d801111a982480111299a9824199ab9a33720010004094092266a0660186601e01601a2a66a6090666ae68cdc8804001024825099a819803198078070028a99a982419809003800899a81980619807805806899a81980319807807002990009aa82111091299a9a8130008a814110a99a981f19804002240002006266a600c240026600e00890010009119b8100200122333573466e240080040e80e4488cc00ccc01cc018008c018004cc894cd4d40c0008854cd4d40c400884cd4c0b80088cd4c0bc0088cc034008004888100888cd4c0c401081008894cd4c104ccd5cd19b87006003043042153353041333573466e1c01400810c1084cc0380100044108410840ec54cd4d40c0004840ec40ecc014008c014004894cd4c0d8008400440dc88ccd5cd19b8700200103703623530240012200123530230012200222335302d0022335302e00223300500200120352335302e002203523300500200122333573466e3c0080040cc0c8c8004d540e08844894cd4d407000454078884cd407cc010008cd54c018480040100048848cc00400c0088004888888888848cccccccccc00402c02802402001c01801401000c00880048848cc00400c0088004848c004008800448800848800480048c8c8cccd5cd19b8735573aa004900011981519191999ab9a3370e6aae75400520002375c6ae84d55cf280111931a981899ab9c02703203002f137540026ae854008dd69aba135744a004464c6a605c66ae700900bc0b40b04d55cf280089baa00123232323333573466e1cd55cea801a4000466600e602c6ae85400cccd5403dd719aa807bae75a6ae854008cd4071d71aba135744a004464c6a605c66ae700900bc0b40b04d5d1280089aab9e5001137540024442466600200800600440022464646666ae68cdc39aab9d5002480008cc88cc024008004dd71aba1500233500a232323333573466e1cd55cea80124000466446601e004002602c6ae854008ccd5403dd719aa809919299a981419805a800a40022a00226a05c921022d33001375a00266aa01eeb88c94cd4c0a0cc02d400520001500113502e491022d32001375a0026ae84d5d1280111931a981719ab9c02402f02d02c135573ca00226ea8004d5d09aba25002232635302a33573804005605205026aae7940044dd500091199ab9a33712004002040042442466002006004400244246600200600440022464460046eb0004c8004d5408c88cccd55cf80092804119a80398021aba1002300335744004048224464460046eac004c8004d5408c88c8cccd55cf80112804919a80419aa80618031aab9d5002300535573ca00460086ae8800c0944d5d0800889100109109119800802001890008891119191999ab9a3370e6aae754009200023355008300635742a004600a6ae84d5d1280111931a981099ab9c01702202001f135573ca00226ea8004448848cc00400c0084480048c8c8cccd5cd19b8735573aa004900011980318071aba1500233500a2323232323333573466e1d40052002233300e375a6ae854010dd69aba15003375a6ae84d5d1280191999ab9a3370ea004900011808180a9aba135573ca00c464c6a604666ae700640900880840804d55cea80189aba25001135573ca00226ea8004d5d09aba25002232635301c33573802403a03603426aae7940044dd5000910919800801801100090911801001911091199800802802001900089119191999ab9a3370ea002900011a80418029aba135573ca00646666ae68cdc3a801240044a010464c6a603066ae7003806405c0580544d55cea80089baa001121223002003112200112001232323333573466e1d4005200223006375c6ae84d55cf280191999ab9a3370ea0049000118041bae357426aae7940108c98d4c04ccd5ce00480a00900880809aab9d50011375400242446004006424460020064002921035054310012253353003333573466e3cd4c01800888008d4c018004880080140104ccd5cd19b873530060022200135300600122001005004100412200212200120012212330010030022001235002490101310012326353003335738002008004930900090008891918008009119801980100100081049fd8799f581cdef9fafd9028d9d3d9889fc3a8ac689d675909444e749555c56262ee9fd8799fd8799fd8799f581c8557ea6f0e3ea5bc9d85a9d6b0e13707411073fa94c955901afb8f3cffd8799fd8799fd8799f581c658203e43a0d07909fab7b5c8127cb89c9ed0a237fb745b37a3e546fffffffffa140d8799f00a1401a000f4240ffffd8799fd8799fd8799f581c70e60f3b5ea7153e0acc7a803e4401d44b8ed1bae1c7baaad1a62a72ffd8799fd8799fd8799f581c1e78aae7c90cc36d624f7b3bb6d86b52696dc84e490f343eba89005fffffffffa140d8799f00a1401a000f4240ffffd8799fd8799fd8799f581cdef9fafd9028d9d3d9889fc3a8ac689d675909444e749555c56262eeffd8799fd8799fd8799f581c771930a167f20ba82bc54ff63914994d77e99762934c4350cc85accaffffffffa140d8799f00a1401a002dc6c0ffffffffff0581840001d87a80821a0037925a1a4d225acff5f6"
}
```

What did I do wrong, or what do I have to do for it to succeed?
Do you have an idea? Would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CBOR is in cddl format, so the `type` must be "Unwitnessed Tx AlonzoEra".

When using one of the cli cmds to build the transaction body (`build` or `build-raw`) then using `--cddl-format` flag will do this for you.